# Spring 3 - Including javascript through a JSP view resolver?

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, localization

I'm trying to localize my application, and it would be nice if I could simply send all JS files through a JSP resolver to get access to localization bundles.

Right now, I just have this:

```
<bean id="viewResolver" class=
        "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
</bean>
```

and I was wondering if there was an easy way to have both `.js` and `.jsp` resolve through the `InternalResourceViewResolver` without adding in some pattern matching hackery.

Comment: What do you want to do: have a js file for each language (like property files), or put some language dependen placeholder in a (one) js file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't actually need your `.js` files to be stored as `.js`, as long as their content-type is `text/javascript`. But having dynamic information in your `.js` files is wrong:

- you cannot cache them properly
- you might be tempted to add jsp logic in the .js file, which will be hard to maintain
- you cannot use contend-delivery networks (if needed)
- (and perhaps there are more downsides to that, which I can't think of right now)

Instead, you should initialize some settings object from a jsp page that is using the .js file. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5595868/spring-mvc-3-populate-javascript-var-from-property-file/5596025#5596025) for more details.

Here is a concrete (simplified) example from my code. This snippet is in the `.jsp`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var config = {
    root : "${root}",
    language: "${user.language.code}",
    currentUsername: "${user.username}",
    messages : {
        reply : "${msg.reply}",
        delete : "${msg.delete}",
        loading : "${msg.loading}",
    }
};
init(config);
</script>
```

The `init(config)` is in the `.js` file, and is just setting the config object as a global variable. (I actually have some default values, but that doesn't matter)

Comment: The dynamic information will be localization and user name parameterization, although I guess that does prevent caching.

Comment: @Stefan Kendall I'm having the same scenario. Take a look at the code I'll add in a moment

Answer (score 0):

Put all your javascripts under `webapp/scripts`. Then programmatically add this implementation of the `addResourceHandlers()` method to your WebConfig.xml:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "package.base.your")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

//your other WebMvcConfigurerAdapter class implementations here

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
  //other handlers here
  registry.addResourceHandler("/scripts/**").addResourceLocations("/scripts/**");
}
```