# spring mvc 3 populate javascript var from property file

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I need to populate a JavaScript variable with a property value (that defined in a property file) when page get loaded . i am using spring mvc 3. is there any best way to do it? appreciate if someone give me some clue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create an initializer method in the javascript file
- output the properties in the page that includes the js. so that they form a valid javascript structure (array, object, whatever)
- pass the structure to the initializer.

The 1st step may look like (in the .js file):

```
var options;
function init(initOptions) {
   options = initOptions;
}
```

The 2nd step may look like (in your jsp page):

```
var a = new Array();
<c:forEach items="${properties}" var="entry">
   a.push({key: '${entry.key}', value: '${entry.value}'});
</c:forEach>
```

And finally `init(a);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but i am still unclear about the second step. can you please explain it bit further? so it is nothing to do with spring is it?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. i think 'properties' attribute will come to the jsp from spring mvc side. am i correct? or else is there any tag library that i can access property files directly from jsp?

Comment: yes, correct. You can set it in the request by a controller. Or expose it as bean to the servlet context. It depends on the scope of these properties.

Comment: Thanks a lot. now i got it. Appreciate your time and effort Bozho.